# Dictionary with same keys and sometimes same

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data that is returned from a MySQL query with:

```
print row[0], row[1], row[2]
```

Resulting in:

```
E25 2016-03-20 2016-03-29
E26 2016-03-18 2016-03-27
E26 2016-03-25 2016-04-02
E27 2016-03-20 2016-03-28
E20 2016-03-19 2016-03-28
E21 2016-03-22 2016-03-28
E21 2016-03-25 2016-04-04
E21 2016-03-25 2016-04-04
E22 2016-03-20 2016-03-27
etc.....
```

I'd like to place this in a dictionary so that it can be used later and called in a function that requires a start and end date. How can I build a dictionary from this data?

Edit: Here is the full print:

```
for row in cursor:
    print row[0], row[1], row[2]
```

For instances of the same key I'd like the different date range to stay with that key.

**EDIT** In case someone needs the answer I was able to come up with:

```
run_dict = defaultdict(list)
for row in cursor:
    run_dict[row[0]].append([row[1], row[2]])
```

Comment: `dictionary[row[0]] = (row[1], row[2])`

Comment: You have to explain what you want for the duplicate keys, example E26

Comment: If you print 3 elements you get 10+ lines? Could you please show what only ``row[0]`` looks like?

Comment: For E26 it would create two lists

Comment: You need to make each dictionary value a list of lists, so that when you get a duplicate key you can append to the list.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question below in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs the answer I was able to come up with:

```
run_dict = defaultdict(list)
for row in cursor:
    run_dict[row[0]].append([row[1], row[2]])
```